# NuxtJS + VueJS + static javascript game

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I am creating a website with simple javascript games
I store the games under `/static` so fx `/static/somegame/` which has an `index.html` file with a bunch of stuff

However, if I am on my root page `index.vue` and I click a button that should route me over to `somegame` it does not load, however, the address bar says `http://localhost:3000/somegame` and if I reload the page, the game loads.

What static `magic` must I do?

Note: The nuxt app is running in `spa` mode ... but I am open to anything

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt by default creates an instance of Vue-router and maps the files in your `/pages` directory to the appropriate routes. So if you want to reach something at `http://localhost:3000/somegame`, you would create a file called `somegame.vue` in the `/pages` directory.

Difficult to imagine exactly why you’d want to use index.html files inside a nuxt project— can you move the code from there and place it in the page files (.vue) instead?

Comment: Users are supposed to be able to upload their own games, i.e not made by me, and a suggestion I saw somewhere was keep them in the static folder

Comment: This sounds like a reasonably complex scenario... are there any restrictions as to what users can upload? Are the games then supposed to be integrated into your nuxt app automatically?

Comment: The owner (not me) will administrate and decide what games will be accepted, but he has no technical knowhow beyond copy pasting folders and clicking 'build' in jenkins